# How to remove array using splice method

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've created (3) lists. What I'm trying to do:

-When the checkbox is checked, push values into the mainArray (which I've gotten to work)

-When the checkbox unchecked, remove values from the mainArray.

For example: If input A is unchecked, remove [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] from the mainArray.

Any help or input here would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.input-1')
const b = document.querySelector('.input-2')
const c = document.querySelector('.input-3')

const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const list3 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

const mainArray = [];

a.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (a.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!a.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list)
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
});

b.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (b.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list2)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!b.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list2)
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
})


c.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (c.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list3)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!c.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list3)
    if (index != -1) {
      list3.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="input-1" type="checkbox"
value = "a"> A

<input class="input-2" type="checkbox"
value = "b"> B

<input class="input-3" type="checkbox"
value = "c"> C
```

Any help, or input here would be appreciated.

Comment: `list.splice` should be `mainArray.splice`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! I've just changed `list.splice` to `mainArray.splice`

Comment: You also should just splice 1 element, not all elements starting from `index`.

Comment: Apart from splice, is there another array method which removes that entire array from the mainArray when its unchecked?

Comment: You can use `delete mainArray[index]`, but that leaves a gap in the array.

Comment: Note that the array is just one element of `mainArray`. `push()` doesn't concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete only one, so make sure you pass the second param.

```js
mainArray.splice(index, 1);
```

You can also make this more generic by accessing a list at the index of the letter e.g. a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, etc... by normalizing the character codes into an index.

### Full example

```js
const mainArray = [];

const lists = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
];

const handleClick = (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  const listIndex = input.value.charCodeAt(0) - 97;
  const foundList = lists[listIndex];

  if (input.checked) {
    mainArray.push(foundList);
  } else {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(foundList);
    if (index !== -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mainArray));
};

document.querySelectorAll('.list')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', handleClick));
```

```html
<input class="list" type="checkbox" value="a"> A
<input class="list" type="checkbox" value="b"> B
<input class="list" type="checkbox" value="c"> C
```

A better way to achieve this would be to make the mail list mutable and just replace the value. When updating the value, just look at the current selections and reduce the lists.

```js
let mainList = []; // Make this mutable...

const subLists = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
];

const syncChoices = (inputs, lists) =>
  [...inputs].reduce((acc, { checked }, index) =>
    checked ? [...acc, ...lists[index]] : acc, []);

const handleClick = (e) => {
  mainList = syncChoices(document.querySelectorAll('.list'), subLists); // Set

  console.log(JSON.stringify(mainList)); // Print the list
};

document.querySelectorAll('.list')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', handleClick));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4em !important; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="list" data-index="0"> A
<input type="checkbox" class="list" data-index="1"> B
<input type="checkbox" class="list" data-index="2"> C
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Polywhirl. This solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way to accomplish the same thing.
Each time you click a checkbox, it recalculates `mainArray` from scratch, using the currently selected checkboxes and their `data-list` attributes to build it.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".listy")].forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const mainArray = [...document.querySelectorAll(".listy:checked")].flatMap(el => JSON.parse(el.dataset.list));
    console.log(mainArray);
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="listy" type="checkbox"
value = "a" data-list="[1,2,3,4,5]"> A

<input class="listy" type="checkbox"
value = "b" data-list="[6,7,8,9,10]"> B

<input class="listy" type="checkbox"
value = "c" data-list="[11,12,13,14,15]"> C
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing `mainArray` instead of `list`.

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.input-1')
const b = document.querySelector('.input-2')
const c = document.querySelector('.input-3')

const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const list3 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

const mainArray = [];

a.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (a.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!a.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list)
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
});

b.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (b.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list2)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!b.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list2)
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
})


c.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (c.checked) {
    mainArray.push(list3)
    console.log(mainArray)
  } 
  
  else if (!c.checked) {
    let index = mainArray.indexOf(list3)
    if (index != -1) {
      mainArray.splice(index)
      console.log(mainArray)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="input-1" type="checkbox"
value = "a"> A

<input class="input-2" type="checkbox"
value = "b"> B

<input class="input-3" type="checkbox"
value = "c"> C
```

Comment: Thanks @Spectric for the reply. The solution you provided is pushing the values into the mainArray, however when I uncheck a box some weird behavior appears. 

For example, if I select "A", "B", and "C" it pushes [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]] to the array. 

Than, when I uncheck "B" than [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] displays, when it should be displaying  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing the same:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]],
      cbs=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")

document.body.onchange=()=>
console.log(arr.filter((_,i)=>
  cbs[i].checked).flat() );
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> A</label> <label><input type="checkbox"> B</label> <label><input type="checkbox"> C</label>
```

In a real use case you will probably need to limit the selector `document.body` to the actual container surrounding the checkboxes.

If you *really, really* want to do it with `.splice()` then maybe the following could be a way to do it:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]],
      cbs=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

document.body.onchange=()=>{ 
  for(var res=arr.slice(0),i=cbs.length;i--;) if(!cbs[i].checked) res.splice(i,1);
  console.log(res.flat());
};
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> A</label> <label><input type="checkbox"> B</label> <label><input type="checkbox"> C</label>
```

In order to preserve the original array I create a shallow copy first with `.slice(0)`. The `for` loop is then made to count down from the highest index to zero, `splice`ing away an element from the `res`-array whenever the associated `cbs`-element is *not* checked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Carsten Massmann. Is there any way to integrate the splice method here to fit into the code I wrote?

Comment: Please check again, I added a second snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is right but the way you're using arr.splice() is wrong.

For it to work in your case you should give a second argument to splice to inform how many elements you wish to remove

Ex:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

arr.splice(3,10)
```

This will remove all elements starting from index 3 in the array.

Since in your case you pre defined the number of elements in each array you wish to remove i believe using this method will be the simplest way.

There are also other ways to use splice() where you can select the exact element you wish to remove.

Here's the link, everything u need to know about splice will be [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),

Comment: Also you're referencing list instead of mainArray as the guy from answer below said

Comment: @John Galt, @Dharman I appreciate the input. If I do remove the item like this: `mainArray.splice(index, 1)` It will just remove the index value (list-1, list-2, or list-3) in the "1" position of the array. It the array values are not are not selected in the order of A, B, C than this could push the wrong values into the mainArray.